# Mysql Synchronization for multiple servers

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I'm at a loss for what to do for my use-case aside from just build my own, but perhaps someone here knows of a program to do it?

Here goes,

I have multiple users (like 15), each has a tablet that they do work on, that work gets stored into a mysql database on the tablet. The work also requires data from all other databases. There is also a main database that many users connect to to get information off of and write to. This data must also be distributed to the tablets.

This is all because the tablets are often offline, and must work offline, and sync back when they get service.

There is no need to compare data or anything. Data is just a row in a table, it basically just needs to be stored as a new row, duplicates do not matter even.

flow of data

- user enters data on tablet
- data gets stored in local DB
- if there is a connection, data copies to main DB
- main DB distributes data to other tablets
- if other tablets, some do not have link, it will send them when it
  does have a link

More flow

- computer user enters data to main DB
- Main DB distributes the data to all tablets

All of the main DB to tablet connections are handled with SSH tunnels. the Main DB has connection to all tablets whenever they are in signal. 
The tablets do not have a connection to each other.

**EDIT**

Just found this here, I knew of replication, but did not know it can now do multi-master. 
https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/02/mysql-5-7-multi-source-replication/

But it sounds like it will start a process of defecation as soon as the tablets lose cell signal or are turned off.
I'll test it next week though.

Comment: to distributes the main db to the tablets are easy. you can do it with the normal Master / Slave replication. so each tablet is a slave and connected to to the public master server. The way to replicate to the Master DB is bot so easy. there are many questions like: can every tablet change the same record ? then is the problem which one is the newest or how to combine the date. Do you have a little more info about your project ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen the project is just a simple form the users fill out using the tablets in the field, from there it breaks that up in software to form the Row in the DB. The users will not change anything, if they make a mistake, they will load the old one and submit a new one. For working with the data and duplicates, it will simply use the newest one.

Comment: graet, so you can have 2 schemas on each tablet. one is the replicated schema from the master DB. the second is where the tablet writes in each data. the trick is to use a Auto increment lets say 20 and offset for the auto increment for each Tablet like userid 1 to 19. so tablet 1 writes id 1,11,21,... then the tablet can take a look if they can connect to master and copy his records to an schema, all in the same table. If you want we can email or phone about it and put the result later here